# Meteor autoform "afFieldValueIs" with a boolean checkbox only triggers once

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a checkbox that needs to show/hide another input box. I'm doing the following:

Schema:

```
isFlexibleTime:
   type: Boolean
   label: 'Is the start time flexible?'
flexibleTimeDetails:
   type: String
   label: 'Flexible time details'
   optional: true
```

Template:

```
+afQuickField(name='isFlexibleTime')

if afFieldValueIs name='isFlexibleTime' value=true
    +afQuickField(name='flexibleTimeDetails')
```

The helper will trigger one time and show the other field but it won't trigger again. Any help into what is wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EDIT

Actually on further inspection it seems there is currently a bug with the checkbox event as of AutoForm 5.1.2 https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/861

The issue has been open a little while, so you can use a quick workaround like:

In your template event:

```
'click [name=isFlexibleTime]': function() {
    Session.set('isFlexibleTime', AutoForm.getFieldValue('isFlexibleTime','ID_OF_YOUR_AUTOFORM'));
}
```

Template helper:

```
isChecked: function() {
            return Session.get('isFlexibleTime');
}
```

then:

```
{{#if isChecked}}
         {{> afQuickField name="flexibleTimeDetails"}}
{{/if}}
```

---

I'm not sure if that's your actual syntax but following the example from: http://autoform.meteor.com/fieldvalues it should look like this:

```
 {{> afQuickField name="isFlexibleTime"}}
 {{#if afFieldValueIs name="isFlexibleTime" value="true"}}
      {{> afQuickField name="flexibleTimeDetails"}}
 {{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Jon. That is great to know. I will just monitor that PR and pull the fix once it is merged.